# Upload new image in asset library in SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, rest, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am developing a SharePoint Hosted app for SharePoint Online. Now I wondered if there is a way to upload a new image file to the central asset library.

I found several code snippets for C#, but my requirement is to use only Javascript.

Is there a simple API for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look this sample from MSDN.
Provider-hosted apps written in JavaScript must use the SP.RequestExecutor cross-domain library to send requests to a SharePoint domain.
You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
    }
});

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
function uploadFile() {

    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

    // Get the server URL.
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    var getFile = getFileBuffer();
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

        // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
        addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

            // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
            var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert('file uploaded and updated');
                });
                changeItem.fail(onError);
            });
            getItem.fail(onError);
        });
        addFile.fail(onError);
    });
    getFile.fail(onError);

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }

    // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
    function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

        // Send the request and return the response.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileListItemUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }

    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
    function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

        // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
        // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
        // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
        // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
        var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
            itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

        // Send the request and return the promise.
        // This call does not return response content from the server.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: itemMetadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length": body.length,
                "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}
```

[Upload a file by using the REST API and jQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx)