# Where to store publishing images

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, publishing-page

I've two site collections:

1. an authoring like portal where authors creates the articles
2. the intranet or publishing portal

The articles will be created within a page in SharePoint in this page there exist the publishing HTML and publishing image column.

I created an app that replace the image dialog for setting the image. The image will be returned to the column. But I found out that it stores only the image url.

Does it not store the binary of the image? If not, what is the best place to store the image? In the publishing portal or the authoring portal?

n.b.: I hope that there exist a solution the "synchronize" the images from one asset-like folder to the target folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog only takes the URL, it is up to you as a developer what to do with it.

I presume you are on 2013

See code at

[Upload new image in asset library in SharePoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138893/upload-new-image-in-asset-library-in-sharepoint-online)

Search for [Cross-Site Publishing](https://www.google.nl/search?q=cross-site+publishing&oq=cross-site+publishing)  on how to 'sync' your (Asset) Libraries.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635883.aspx
- http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-2013-cross-site-publishing

Comment: So I understand this article that I must take the solution that I "upload" the files into the publishing portal and not in the authoring portal. Thx for the help.